# grep function not working

Tags: bash, grep

what am I doing wrong in the code below?

I am replacing the salary data within the text file, but the `Telephone number` field (the 3rd column) is being updated instead of the `salary` field (the 5th column) which is 0.

In the example below, the calculated salary for Ruben is 500.

My Desired output is:

`Ruben,1223,97707001,Salaried,500`

But instead, I get this (replacing zero between 9770 and 7001 with 535):

`Ruben,1223,9775007001,Salaried,0`

```
payroll_employee()
{

   echo
   echo "[Option: $input]"
   echo "Enter Payroll of an employee "
   echo
   echo -en "Enter employee name: "
   read Name

  #Retrieve current entry into individual fields                                                        
  line=`grep -i "$Name" $PAYROLL`
  Name=`echo $line | cut -d "," -f1`
  EmployeeID=`echo $line | cut -d "," -f2`
  EmployeeHP=`echo $line | cut -d "," -f3`
  EmployeeType=`echo $line | cut -d "," -f4` 
  Salary=`echo $line | cut -d "," -f5` 

  #Check if entry exist in records
   if [ `count_lines "^${Name},"` -eq 0 ]
   then
       echo "Error: This particular record does not exist!!"
   else
      echo "$Name is ${EmployeeType} employee."


   if [ "$EmployeeType" = "Salaried" ]
   then
    echo $EmployeeType  
    echo -en "Enter Weekly Salary:"
    read swages                     
    if [ -z $swages ]
        then
        swages=$Salary
        else     
        grep -vi "$Name" $PAYROLL > tmpfile      #Perform updating to salary field entry
        grep -x "$line" $PAYROLL | sed -e "s/$Salary/$swages/" >> tmpfile
        mv tmpfile $PAYROLL
        echo "$Name's weekly payroll has been updated to \$$swages!!"
        fi
    echo
}
```

Sample code:

```
update_employee()
{
  echo
  echo "[Option: $input]"
  echo "Updating employee record... "
  echo "Please enter the name of the employee to update: "
  echo -en "[1]Name: "
  read update_name

  #Retrieve current entry into individual fields                                                        
  line=`grep -i "$update_name" $PAYROLL`
  oldname=`echo $line | cut -d "," -f1`
  oldjob=`echo $line | cut -d "," -f2`
  olddept=`echo $line | cut -d "," -f3`
  oldsal=`echo $line | cut -d "," -f4` 

  #Check if entry to update exist in records
  if [ `count_lines "^${update_name},"` -eq 0 ]
  then
     echo "Error: This particular record does not exist!!"
  else
     while [ "$choice" != "6" ]
     do
        update_menu    #Display update menu for user input,allows update of individual field or all at once
        read update_choice
        case $update_choice in
             "1")  echo -en "Please enter employee's new name: " 
                   read new_name 
                   if [ -z $new_name ]
                   then
                      new_name=$oldname
                   elif [ `count_lines "^${new_name},"` -ne 0 ]  #Check if name already exist in records
                   then
                      echo "Error: Employee [$new_name] already exist in records!"
                   else  
                      grep -vi "$oldname" $PAYROLL > tmpfile     #Perform updating to name field entry
                      grep -x "$line" $PAYROLL | sed -e "s/$oldname/$new_name/" >> tmpfile
                      mv tmpfile $PAYROLL   
                      echo "Employee's name $oldname has been updated to [$new_name]!!"
                   fi
                   break
                   ;; }
```

All I changed was add one more column.

```
  Salary=`echo $line | cut -d "," -f5`
```

Comment: kbear `if [ "$EmployeeType" = "Salaried" ]`  its not OK it has to be `if [ "$EmployeeType" == "Salaried" ]` as its string match check

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you are replacing every occurrence of the string `$Salary` in the payroll line, so if salary is `100` and the employee ID number is `2100`, it will be replaced.

Instead of using `sed` at the end, you would probably be better off generating the output using `printf` and building the fields up that way.

Something like:

```
printf "%s,%s,%s,%s,%s\n" $Name $EmployeeID $EmployeeHP $EmployeeType $swages >> tmpfile
```

---

**EDIT**: You should fix the `=` to `==` as pointed out in the comments.
Also, to illustrate what I think is happening:

```
line="ABC,5100,DEF,100"
Salary=100
echo $line | sed -e s/${Salary}/XXX/

ABC,5XXX,DEF,100
```

If you "anchor" the query by putting a `$` at the end of the search string, it will only match the last value.

```
echo $line | sed -e s/${Salary}$/XXX/ 

ABC,5100,DEF,XXX
```

**Add some `echo` statements in your code to check the status of variables....**

Comment: can i use the same grep function to make it work. I'm actually referring to some sample code (updated in my question). All i changed was to add Salary=`echo $line | cut -d "," -f5`.

Comment: I am not totally clear on your question about the grep function. The `sed` part is what is not working. Also the other comment about using `==` instead of `=` in your test is important. But the current `sed` is going to change it everywhere. You might be able to put a `$` at the END of the `sed` query (after `$Salary`) to make sure the number matches at the end of the line only.

Answer (score 0):

```
payroll_employee()
{

   echo
   echo "[Option: $input]"
   echo "Enter Payroll of an employee "
   echo
   echo -en "Enter employee name: "
   read Name

  #Retrieve current entry into individual fields                                                        

  if [ $(grep -ciw "$Name" $PAYROLL) -eq 0 ]
  then
    echo "No matches found in $PAYROLL";
  else
   line=$(grep -iw "$Name" $PAYROLL);
  Name=$(echo $line | awk -F "," print $1);
  EmployeeID=$(echo $line | awk -F "," print $2);
  EmployeeHP=$(echo $line | awk -F "," print $3);
  EmployeeType=$(echo $line | awk -F "," print $4);
  Salary=$(echo $line | awk -F "," print $5);

  fi

   if [ "$EmployeeType" == "Salaried" ]
   then
    echo $EmployeeType  
    echo -en "Enter Weekly Salary:"
    read swages                     
    if [ -z $swages ]
        then
        swages=$Salary
        else  
        sed "/$Name/d" $PAYROLL
    echo "$Name $EmployeeID $EmployeeHP $EmployeeType $swages" >> $PAYROLL;
        echo "$Name's weekly payroll has been updated to \$$swages!!"
        fi
    echo
}
```

I Prefer use of AWK for delimination

also you can delete line using

`sed "/$Name/d" $PAYROLL`

Why to store it in other file using grep -vi and rename back and replace with original (Waste of memory & resources)

also "`" backtick should be replaced with new method of using $(..)

Also one make sure when you match strings use == sign

also in grep use -w also just to make sure that you select proper complete string
Ruben baruben rubenner all will be searched in grep if -w is not given